# pandas read_sql_table() issue from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect to a sqlserver database and read my data into a data frame.  This is my code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sq

engine = sq.create_engine('mssql://ServerName/myDataBase?trusted_connection=yes')

df_sql = pd.read_sql_table("TableName",con=engine,schema="App")
```

I am getting this error message:

> NotImplementedError: read_sql_table only supported for SQLAlchemy connectable.

I don't know if I am missing anything in the syntax to get this connection to read into a dataframe.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166179/errors-trying-to-read-access-database-tables-into-pandas-with-pyodbc) is at the top of my internet search on the error message. Have you tried `read_sql` instead of `read_sql_table`?

Comment: @DanGuzman - The thing is that `create_engine()` returns an `Engine` object, specifically `class Engine(Connectable, log.Identified)`, so it *is* a Connectable. And since `df = pd.read_sql_table("team", con=engine, schema="dbo")` works for me I must conclude that there's something else going on that OP isn't telling us.